# form_assign.validate() always returns False

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

*I can't make validation form. form_assign.validate() always returns False.*

**views:**

```
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///' + os.path.join(APP_ROOT, 'app', 'data', 'xxx.sqlite')+'?check_same_thread=False')
session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))
inspector = inspect(engine)

metadata = MetaData()
metadata.reflect(engine)
Base = automap_base(metadata=metadata)
Base.prepare()

def property():
    form = Property()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form_assign = Property(request.form)
        if form_assign.validate():
            _form = request.form.to_dict()
            if 'btn_save' in _form:
                form_dict = request.form.to_dict()
                name_button_1 = 'btn_save'
                return add_to_db(form_dict, table, name_button_1)
    context_cement = {
        'heading': heading,
    
    }
    return app_api.render_page(mod.name + "/compound_forms.html", **context_cement)
```

*I did like this:*
**views:**

```
def property():
    form = Property()
    if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate():
```

*I had the same trouble. *

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used Flask-wtf to define the class `Property`, but it is used as a more basic `FlaskForm` direct from Wtforms.

With Flask-wtf, you either need `{{ form.csrf_token }}` or `{{ form.hidden_tag() }}` in the html code of `compound_forms.html` (no need of both)
(https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/1.0.x/csrf/?highlight=csrf
and https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/1.0.x/quickstart/#creating-forms )

Adapting the html code of `compound_forms.html` you showed in comment. You might want to simplify to

```
<form method="POST" action="/">
   {{ form.csrf_token }}
   {{ form.id_assign }}
   <input type="submit" value="Save" name="btn_save">
</form>
```

(I did not understand the `{{ form.form_type }}` and there must be missing code with the `{% for field in form if field.name != 'csrf_token' %}` in comment)

Also as you used Flask-Wtf in `views:`. You also can simplify :

```
def property():
    form_assign = Property()  # no need of Property(request.form)
    if form_assign.validate_on_submit(): # instead of validate()  , checks if it is a POST
        _form = request.form.to_dict()
        if 'btn_save' in _form: # not sure why you need that
            form_dict = request.form.to_dict()
            name_button_1 = 'btn_save'
            return add_to_db(form_dict, table, name_button_1)
    context_cement = {'heading': heading}
    return app_api.render_page(mod.name + "/compound_forms.html", **context_cement)
```

Comment: I made it. When I write 'if form_assign.validate():' object does not save in database, validator worked ( IntegerField('ID', [validators.DataRequired(message="PLease enter uniq ID.")]) - in form.py). When I delete string ''if form_assign.validate():" object save.

Comment: It seems you have another problem, this time with the "ID" IntegerField.  You need to show how you defined `Property` (is it a Wftorms , or from flask-wtf) and if it is present in the html (`compound_forms.html`)